# Sorting records first by numbers and then alphabets in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, mariadb

I have a table called "test" which has a column called "custom_id", which can be a mixture of alphabets and integers. I want a MySQL query to first sort it based on integers and then based on Alphabets in the string. I.e:

```
Input:
1b
1a
Apple5
Apple1
Bapple2
Bapple5
2a
3

Output (in ASC):
1a
1b
Apple1
2a
Bapple2
3
Apple5
Bapple5
```

The above is a bit different from natural sorting since it doesn't sort based on the length of the string. I have following query that works in MariaDB but I am looking for a MySQL solution (no procedures please):

```
SELECT custom_id FROM test
ORDER BY CAST(REGEXP_SUBSTR(custom_id,'[0-9]+') AS UNSIGNED) ASC, custom_id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

`0+custom_id` would give the value of the leading number.  If there are no leading zeros, then `LENGTH(0+custom_id)` would say how much to strip off.  Use a suitable `MID(...)` to do fetch the characters after that many.